# on load scroll automatically to div on left in horizontal layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onload

i am a newb to jquery

i have a metro (horizontal layout)

```
<pre>

<section id="content" >

            <section class="clearfix section" id="sharing-experience" style="margin-top: 100px; height: 525px;">

                <h3 class="block-title">first</h3>

                <div class="tile turquoise w3 h2 icon-fadeoutscaleup">
                    <a class="link" href="#">
                        <i class="fa-bookmark"></i>
                        <p class="title-right">one</p>
                        <p class="title">1</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="tile brown w3 h2 icon-fadeoutscaleup">
                    <a class="link" href="#">
                        <i class="fa-clipboard"></i>
                        <p class="title-right">two</p>
                        <p class="title">2</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </section>
<section class="clearfix section" id="sharing-experience" style="margin-top: 100px; height: 525px;">

                <h3 class="block-title">second</h3>

                <div class="tile turquoise w3 h2 icon-fadeoutscaleup">
                    <a class="link" href="#">
                        <i class="fa-bookmark"></i>
                        <p class="title-right">one</p>
                        <p class="title">1</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="tile brown w3 h2 icon-fadeoutscaleup">
                    <a class="link" href="#">
                        <i class="fa-clipboard"></i>
                        <p class="title-right">two</p>
                        <p class="title">2</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </section>
<section class="clearfix section" id="sharing-experience" style="margin-top: 100px; height: 525px;">

                <h3 class="block-title">third</h3>

                <div class="tile turquoise w3 h2 icon-fadeoutscaleup">
                    <a class="link" href="#">
                        <i class="fa-bookmark"></i>
                        <p class="title-right">one</p>
                        <p class="title">1</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="tile brown w3 h2 icon-fadeoutscaleup">
                    <a class="link" href="#">
                        <i class="fa-clipboard"></i>
                        <p class="title-right">two</p>
                        <p class="title">2</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </section>


</section>

</pre>
```

The page on ready should start from the third section
for that there should be an animation from right to left on the page loads or ready

here is the example
which is been done
if anybody could help!! it will be really great
and here is the link for the metro design
i am using megametro

here is the link for it
http://themes.grozav.com/metromega/

Comment: Uhm, where do you have the code for animation?

Comment: nop i dont have it right now but i tried giving this .animate(500) left on page load

Answer (score 0):

HI i suppose you want to have section 3 in the center of the page when the page loads and the other two sections to the left of it.

If this is what you want, then the following could be done to achieve what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
window.scrollTo($("#id-of-section-you-want-to-show").offset().left ,$("body").offset().left);
```

// apply your animations 
    });

And ya, please do change the id's of your section. Id attribute should be unique since the define a particular dom element in html page.

Comment: if this works for the megametro then it shall work for me also because i have used the same layout

Comment: have you made each id unique ?? You have all sections with id= sharing-experience, please change that, make them sharing-experience-1, sharing-experience-2, or anything that suits your layout. If still things do not work out then let me know'

Comment: Yes, i have changed the ids

Comment: i have made a demo on jsfiddle. please have a look at it [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Sfp6Z/)

Comment: Thanks, but its still not working i dont know whats happening it will be great if i could share you the files for megametro if i could get your email id

Comment: ekanshrastogi@outlook.com